# Tracking the spedup transactions from metamask

Tags: web3js, transactions, metamask, gas

while building a Dapp using metamask to make transactions, i figured that metamask is not responding correctly when a transaction is spedup, making my code wait forever for a canceled transaction that will never finish.

example:

```
const contract = new Contract(abi, address);
await contract.methods.increaseAllowance(address, amount);
// metamask popup shows and i approve,then, while waiting for the Tx to get mined, i hit the speed up button and approve the speedup (sending a new transactions but with more gas)
console.log("allowance increased") // if the transaction is spedup, this code will never run,
```

i can reproduce the issue multiple times, and it doesn't seem like metamask is aware of this. is there a way to fix this ? i don't see a way to listen on transaction speedup in their docs or at least a way to get teh new Tx hash to manually listen on it.

Answer (score 2):

There is one way of tracking this. Follow these steps.

1. Fetch the nonce of the last transaction submitted by the account. In this case, the nonce of `increaseAllowance` called.
2. Subscribe for pending transactions of the account.
3. Check whether a new transaction is submitted with the same nonce. It will be the speed up transaction.

I think, for now this is the only possible way to catch a replacing transaction.